# Let $f (z) = z^2$. Let $Q$ be the square with vertices at $0, 2, 2 + 2i$ and $2i$. Draw $f (Q)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f (z) = z^2$. Let $Q$ be the square with vertices at $0, 2, 2 + 2i$
and $2i$. Draw $f (Q)$ and identify the types of image curves corresponding to the segments from $2$ to $2 + 2i$ and from $2 + 2i$ to $2i$. They are not parts of either straight lines or circles.

I was trying to use the parametrical representation of these for segments:

Case 1: $0 \rightarrow 2$

$x=t, y=0, t: 0 \rightarrow 2$

$$f(z)=f(t)=t^2$$
So $f: 0 \rightarrow 4$. Is it a straight line along the positive reals? Then what is the difference between $t^2, t: 0 \rightarrow 2$ and $t: 0 \rightarrow 4$?

Case 2: $x=2, y=t, t: 0 \rightarrow 2$
$$f(z)=(2+it)^2=(4-t^2)+4ti$$
Still confused...

Any one could help with it and other cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the line $2 + t i, t\in[0,2]$ maps to $(4-t^2) + (4t)i$

If you want to graph this curve.  $x = 4-t^2, yi = 4ti$ is a parabola.

Similarly, $f(t + 2i)$ will also map to a parabola.

Your region looks something like:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In polar form, $z^2 = (re^{i\theta})^2 = r^2e^{2i\theta}$. This means that the action of $z^2$ consists in doubling the angle made between the point and the real axis, and squaring the magnitude of the result. So the vertices $0, 2, 2+2i$ and $2i$ will go into $0, 4, 8i$ and $-4$, ok. It suffices to see the behaviour of $z^2$ in the segment joining $2$ and $2+2i$. Parametrizing, we have $z(t) = 2+2ti$, with $0 \leq t \leq 1$. So $z(t)^2 = 4+8ti-4t^2$, which is the arc of a parabola.

Moral of the history: you'll obtain a "triangle" with vertices at $\pm 4$ and $8i$, but the segments from $4$ to $8i$ and $8i$ to $-4$ are arcs of parabolas.

Comment: Why is the vertex at $4i$ as opposed to $8i$ (just plugging in $t=1$ to $z(t)^2$ gives $8i$).

Comment: @Chubwagon You are correct and it should be $8i$ instead. I will fix it, thanks